# Add weblink as watermark to image

Tags: asp.net, image, gdi+, watermark, navigateurl

I am presently working for watermarking site and I have done completely and everyting is working fine.Now I would like to add a weblink to image as watermark instead of text.

I have tried by taking a hyperlink and adding to Image but it just draws the text and dosen't add it as a URL.

Is it possible to do so?I so how can I achieve this?

This is how I tried to do it:

```
pth.AddString(txtLink.NavigateUrl, New FontFamily(DropFont.SelectedValue), 0, Integer.Parse(DropFontSize.SelectedValue), New Point(left, top), StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
```

Comment: Since when do images have links embedded in them?

Comment: @Aristos-I have seen it for PDF's so I would like it to do for images if possible

Comment: @DotNetter In Pdf they do what oded suggest here (and I vote him +1)

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches come to mind:

- Use anchor elements - `<a>` around your images with the appropriate link.
- Use [image maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) with your images.

Images are images - they don't have links embedded in them that you can click on - you need something extra in order to make them clickable.

Comment: I don't want to add and anchor tag to image instead of that I want to make a link on the image such as  http://www.xyz.com

Comment: @DotNetter - Look at image maps then. You _can't_ add links to images and expect it to work. Images formats don't cater for links.

Comment: you can use dreamviewer for this purpose

Comment: @Athulks - Do you mean dreamweaver? And please tell me, how does it achieve this result? Just with an image element?